# Add LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX to libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so

Tags: c++, macos, tensorflow, bazel

I want to set `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` to libtensorflow dynamic libraries, which I build using bazel.

I've already tried bazel flag: `--copt=-mmacosx-version-min=10.12`
and set environment: `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12`. 
However libtensorflow_framework.so and libtensorflow_cc.so still without `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` flag.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it:
adding `--action_env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12` resolved my problem